# How to access virtual box web server url access from outside network

Tags: linux, oracle, networking

I have the below the setup.

1)Desktop with windows 8 64bit os & Iam using net gear router connected to my desktop via Ethernet cable.

2)Currently iam using public ip or static ip(ex:123.45.67.890)from my isp.

3)Installed virtual box

4)Installed oracle linux 6.5 in virtual box

5)Installed oracle ebs.in virtual box

6)Virtual box network mode:bridge

7)My netgear router ip range 10.0.0.1 to 10.0.0.20

8)Assigned static ip in oracle ebs(10.0.0.30) with port 8000.
 (note:the given ip is not in my router ip range)

9)Added host details(10.0.0.30 ebs.example.com) in my windows system32-->drivers-->etc folder-->host file.

Iam able to access url(http://ebs.example.com:8000) and I can ping ip of oracle ebs(10.0.0.30) from windows 8.and everything is fine.

My requirement is

10)I want to access the same url http://ebs.example.com:8000 from outside of my network.(eg:outside of my city or town).

(Note:I already tried by portforwarding 10.0.0.30 with port 8000 in my router but there is no luck)

Please can anybody help me on this request.

Answer (score 1):

- Virtualbox network interface in bridge mode is transparent to the router. It creates the virtual adapter in software mode and uses injection on your VB host network adapter to have the job done. It means that the router will see your VM as it does for any other computer, like if your VM were directly connected to the router. At this point you should assign a IP on the VM that's on under router IP range to avoid routing/permission/port translation problems.
- Sure you will need port forward on the router but for testing purposes try to set the VM IP as [DMZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DMZ_%28computing%29) on the router. With this setting all requests from outside world on any port will be redirected to the DMZ machine. If it works you can go more restrictive and forward just the needed ports.
- Many ISPS blocks common server ports, like 8080. You must make sure you're using a port not blocked by the ISP. For this try setting up a service on a not common port (like HTTP on port 49010 or whatever port not listed by common services), and test it. If it works change the service to the desired port (8080), if it stops working it probably means that ISP is blocking port 8080.
- You will not be able to access your VM from internet using such address like http://ebs.example.com:8000 or any other [FQN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_name) in a simple manner as it does need DNS translation. Its possible doing so but you will need to buy and register some FQN and then find some service that offer DNS over Dynamic IP. Not sure what you mean by public or static IP because a static IP can be also public. In case you have a static IP you will not need specific services for dynamic IP but just the usual structure: Buy a domain name, buy or use own registar DNS servers to have a working FQN pointing to your IP.
- Another approach is using a non FQN redirection service commonly used for dynamic IPs but that will work on static IPs also like DYN DNS, No-ip or any other.
- With a static IP you dont even need some FQN. You can just use your IP directly like 123.45.67.890:8080 when need connection from internet.